# Trying to Get Three Divs to Align Properly With Another Three Below

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to get three `div`s within the same line to act as titles to three images below them that are centered to the text. I can get right and left to work, but the center one just won't work no matter what I try.

I've tried a lot of different things like messing with `margin` and `padding` values, changing the arrangement of containers, and moving the images to separate `div`s. This is the closest I've gotten:

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFFDD0;
}
header {
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  border: 2px black groove;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: block;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
div {
  text-align: center;
  display: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
h3 {
  clear: none;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
    <header>
        <h1>Brent Tracker Version Log</h1>
    </header>
    <article style="text-align: center;">
        <div style="float: left"><h3>Version 1</h3>
            <a href=""> <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?grayscale"></a>
        </div>
        <div style="margin: auto;">
            <h3>Version 2</h3>
            <a href=""> <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></a>
        </div>
    </article>
```

I know there is probably a really simple solution I'm missing. I'm fairly new to coding.